# I am trying display image when condition is true.but i am getting error in <img> tage pls help me

Tags: java

```
<%
String optionselected =request.getParameter("digram");
out.print(optionselected);`

if(optionselected.equals("1"))
    <img src="C:\Users\jitutjs\workspace\dispImpl\Traing.jpg"/>
else
    if(optionselected.equals("2"))
        <img src="C:\Users\jitutjs\workspace\dispImpl\WebContent\Circle.jpg"/>
    else
        out.print("no diagarm");
%>
```

Comment: Please try to format your questions properly. Also don't post your complete question in the title, but only put a summary there.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="..." />` is not related to java, it is a `html` tag, all that is inside the scriplets is treated as java code. If you want to use scriplets, you must do it like this:

```
<%
String optionselected =request.getParameter("digram");
out.print(optionselected);`

if(optionselected.equals("1"))
%>
<img src="C:\Users\jitutjs\workspace\dispImpl\Traing.jpg"/>
<%
else
    if(optionselected.equals("2"))
 %>
    <img src="C:\Users\jitutjs\workspace\dispImpl\WebContent\Circle.jpg"/>
<%
else
     out.print("no diagarm");
%>
```

P.S. My advice is to not use scriplets, they are old and deprecated. It is better to take a look at [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/get-started.html) tag library.

Answer (score 0):

`img` tag should be out of scriplest. Also, You have given the src value in wrong way, you can use absolute path of your web-app as `<img src="/Circle.jpg"/>` as this may vary when application is deployed elsewhere.